# TableController: Flatten persistent data into DTO

Tags: entity-framework, azure, azure-mobile-services

I'm new to Azure App Service mobile apps.  I'm trying to understand my options for using `TableController` to expose complex domain objects to clients.  My goal of using `TableController` is to take advantage of client-side querying and offline sync.

Table controllers are designed to perform CRUD operations on simple DTOs.  So I'm trying to figure out how a complex domain model could be exposed as the sort of DTOs that `TableController` is designed for.

I've read [this post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuremobile/2014/05/19/mapping-between-database-types-and-client-types-in-the-net-backend-using-automapper/) which explains `MappedEntityDomainManager`.  That example shows a fairly simple mapping between DTOs and persistent objects.  But what if I want my mapping to be more complex?

For example, let's say I have persistent types like this:

```
public class Order {
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public IList<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; }
}

public class Customer {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string TelephoneNumber { get; set; }
}

public class OrderItem { ... }
```

And I have a table controller declared like this:

```
public class OrderController : TableController<OrderDto>
```

Could the `OrderDto` then look like this?

```
public class OrderDto {
    public string CustomerName { get; }
    public string Customer { get; }
    public string OrderItems { get; }
}
```

The mappings would be as follows.  The `Order.Customer.Name` property is flattened into `OrderDto.CustomerName`.  The complete `Customer` object is serialized into `OrderDto.Customer`.  And the `Order.OrderItems` list is serialized into `OrderDto.OrderItems`.

Can this sort of complex mapping be done with `MappedEntityDomainManager`?  If not then how could it be done?  I know about [leveraging `$expand`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuremobile/2014/06/18/insertupdate-data-with-1n-relationship-using-net-backend-azure-mobile-services/), but I worry that may be an unsupported hack rather than the recommended approach.

Comment: your approach looks using sqlite on client side(app) and using noSql on the cloud. This is more or less how amazon web services snyc approach if I understand correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is to use Automapper. The blog post was a simple example, but you can do very complex mapping using automapper.

Here's a more complex example: https://github.com/paulbatum/FieldEngineerLite/blob/master/FieldEngineerLite.Service/Controllers/JobController.cs. It's for Azure Mobile Services, but the same concept applies to Azure Mobile Apps. You just need to change the namespaces.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but the linked example prefers `$expand` over Automapper.  This seems contrary to your recommendation to [include child objects in the parent object](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32999163).  I had your approach in mind in my question, with the `OrderDto.OrderItems` string property containing a serialization of the `Order.OrderItems` list property.   So is the linked example either inappropriate, or should I indeed prefer `$expand` over Automapper in cases the former can be used?

Comment: @HappyNomad This example uses expand *and* automapper. If you look at the domain manager it is using, it's the mapped entity domain manager.

Comment: I did noticed `DefaultMappedEntityDomainManager` and `AutomapperConfiguration`.  Although, those mappings look much simpler than my examples.  Anyway, I think you are recommending `$expand` rather than Automapper for cases like my `OrderItems` example.  So `$expand` is a valid means to "include child objects in the parent object", right?

Comment: No, I'm recommending automapper *and* expand. If your mapping is indeed more complex than the example, then you won't be able to accomplish it with expend alone. Expand and automapper are orthogonal and can't necessarily be used interchangeably.

Comment: Yes but can my example's `OrderItems` be mapped with Automapper alone?

Comment: @HappyNomad You probably need both Automapper and $expand. The FieldEngineer sample uses Automapper to do some name changes, and it uses expand and EF virtual attributes to get child objects. See https://github.com/paulbatum/FieldEngineerLite/blob/master/FieldEngineerLite.Service/App_Start/AutomapperConfiguration.cs.